# How do you use replace_if with a string?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to replace all whitespace characters in each line I'm parsing with a space.  The key line is:

```
replace_if( theString.begin(), theString.end(), ::isspace, " ");
```

The (partial) error I can locate is:

> In function ‘void std::replace_if(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Predicate, const _Tp&) [with _ForwardIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, std::allocator > >, _Predicate = int (*)(int)throw (), _Tp = char [2]]’:
>   instantiated from here

What is the correct usage of replace_if in this situation?  I don't have access to Boost, so I'd prefer pure C++ suggestions please.  I've tried changing " " to string(" ").  I've tried making my own predicate (I am a novice, so don't rule this solution out entirely).  I'd prefer to use replace_if, but will accept an answer explaining why it is too complicated for this situation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to use a character space, in single quotes. Strings are made of characters, not strings.

```
replace_if( theString.begin(), theString.end(), ::isspace, ' ');
```

Comment: This removed the error and the line now works as intended.  Thanks!